# can i turn kivy spinner dropdown options into a button? or can i bind it to call another action?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

```
options = ['What is it for?','What does it do?', 'How does it work?','Why is it necessary?']
About = Spinner(text = 'About', values = options, size_hint = (.2,.1),pos_hint = {'center_x':0.3,'center_y': .8})
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to trigger one action after selecting the option? I don't understand your use case. Please improve your question, so it's more clear what you're looking for and where you're stuck.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.